# How to solve the inequality $(x+3)^2 \le (y+3)^2$ using square roots?

Tags: inequality

I was reading Intermediate Algebra by AoPS when I encountered the inequality $(x+3)^2 \le (y+3)^2$. Their solution consisted of using the difference of squares, which I understand, but is there a way to solve the inequality by first square rooting both sides? I tried to square root the inequality and got $(x+3) \le \pm(y+3)$, which is wrong. How would you solve this inequality?

Comment: It's definitely true that $|{x+3}| \leq |(y+3)|$, does that get you going?

Comment: Think about first solving the simpler problem $x^2 \le y^2$, and consider the four possible cominations of signs for $x$ and $y$ as four separate cases. Then adapt that solution to this slightly harder problem.

Comment: What do you even *mean* by the notation $A \le \pm B$?

Comment: With inequalities, unlike equations, you cannot simply apply a function to both sides and expect the inequality to be respected. Even taking a negative of both sides will require flipping the inequality sign. The key is, if the function is an increasing function, then you can apply it to both sides. If it is decreasing, then you can still apply it, but you must flip the sign. If it is neither, you cannot apply it at all (not without extra work). In this case, taking the positive/negative square root isn't even a function at all, since it has multiple values!

Answer (score 2):

When you take square roots we get mods which you need separate cases to solve

$$
(x+3)^2\le(y+3)^3\Rightarrow|x+3|\le|y+3|
$$

Case 1: $x+3>0,y+3>0$

$$x+3\le y+3\Rightarrow x\le y$$

Case 2: $x+3<0,y+3>0$

$$-x-3\le y+3\Rightarrow 6\le x+y$$

Case 3: $x+3>0,y+3<0$

$$x+3\le -y-3\Rightarrow x+y\le -6$$

Case 4: $x+3<0,y+3<0$

$$-x-3\le -y-3\Rightarrow y\le x$$

These 4 together gives the region that satisfies the inequality but the difference of squares is easier to visualize than 4 separate triangles

Answer (score 1):

In general, since $f(x)=\sqrt x$ is a monotonic increasing function, we have that

$$A^2\le B^2 \iff \sqrt{A^2}\le \sqrt{B^2}$$

then we can use that

$$\sqrt{A^2}=|A|$$

and therefore

$$\sqrt{A^2}\le \sqrt{B^2} \iff |A|\le|B|$$

which produces $4$ different inequalities.